# Description for settings to adjust general app spacing & font-size

Tags: settings, ux-writing

Imagine you want to give users the possibility to adjust the general spacing and font-size of an application to have more contents on smaller screens or whatever reason.

I'm struggling to find a general description for the texts when choosing in a dropdown because the option does not only effect font-size or spacing but the general appearance of the application.

I thought this would be an interesting topic to discuss.

---

**My approach:**

[image]

Comment: Screen size: Small, Medium, and Large.  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're talking about *Information density*.

You can have something like:

Information density:

- Compact
- Standard
- Spacious (or comfort)

PS: I think Gmail has an option for this.

Comment: THAT was the word I was looking for. Fits perfect for my need. Great advice, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[image: Size description]

Additionally, if at all possible, consider representing it as a slider so that users can change it without much of a change in layout.

[image: Sample size changer]
[image]

Comment: Great hint, thanks! As I am not only looking for Text Size it maybe is not the best choice for my problem.